# Scanner class not recognizing many inputs?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // using the Scanner class located in the "java.util" directory

public class Helloworld {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int number =0, count = 0, sum = 0;
        int Largest= 0, largestEvenNumber = 0;

        do {

            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


            number = console.nextInt();


            if (number > Largest) { // Condition for computing the largest number
                Largest = number;
            }

            if (number < 0) { // Condition for computing the number of negative integers in the sequence
                count = count + 1;
            }

            if (number % 2 == 0) { // Condition for computing the largest even integer in the sequence

                if (largestEvenNumber < number) {
                    largestEvenNumber = number;
                }
            }

            if (number % 3 == 0) { // Condition for computing the sum of numbers divisible by 3
                sum += number;
            }

        }while(number != 0);

        System.out.println("\nThe largest integer is " + Largest);
        System.out.println("The number of negative integers in the sequence is " + count);
        System.out.println("The largest even integer in the sequence is " + largestEvenNumber);
        System.out.printf("The sum of numbers divisible by 3 is %d", sum);


    }
}
```

```
output:
1
2
3
```

-1,
-2,
-45,
7,
-9,
23,
67,
900,
0
*No output*

```
Expected output:     
1
2
3
```

-1,
-2,
-45,
7,
-9,
23,
67,
900,
0

```
The largest integer is 900;
The number of negative integers in the sequence is 4;
The largest even integer in the sequence is 900;
The sum of numbers divisible by 3 is 849
```

The program is getting executed when I type the inputs one by one. However,when I try to "Copy Paste" all the inputs at once, from a text editor (inputs are separated in each lines in the text editor) there's no output. I think that the Scanner class is reading only the first number. How do I correct this without creating multiple objects and not typing each number?

Comment: Why do you create new scanners inside a loop? Why not create one before `do-while` loop?

Comment: "*I think that the Scanner class is reading only the first number*" Scanner tries to read as much data as possible and cache remaining part. This is why when you place all data in one line and press ENTER it will be read entirely by one `Scanner` and nothing will be left in `System.in` for other Scanner which will be created in next iteration. That is why we should use one Scanner per resource (if you have many methods which need Scanner handling System.in then either pass that scanner as method parameter, or make in some class Scanner field and access it via getter).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing how the Scanner class work:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("n=" + n);
  }
}
```

You were always reading the first number: you have to first check if you will have a number, then read as a number, then retry until the end of file.

Do note that the Scanner is closed using a try-with-resources which may be unneeded in the case of `System.in`, but not so in other case (files, ...).

Comment: How do I stop the process?